# Fit image into ion-card

Tags: ionic4

Hi I'm trying to fit a image into a ion-card-header, but the image doesn't fit.

I already tried to remove padding, margin and use background-size: cover.

```
<ion-card>
   <ion-card-header no-padding>
      <ion-img [src]="filter.url" no-margin no-padding style="width: 100%;"></ion-img>
   </ion-card-header>

   <ion-card-content>
      <p text-center>{{filter.name}}</p>
   </ion-card-content>
</ion-card>
```

So I want, is that the image stretch if it's small than the ion-card-header, to fit it's size, regardless of the device display.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution!!

I use a media query to set the height that i want and I use object fit (that I didn't know that exist!).

So stayed like this:

```
.image--size {
   width: 100%;
   height: 65.66px;
   object-fit: cover;
}
```